# jQuery click(function() not working but plain Javascript working just fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

THIS IS THE FULL SCRIPT

http://goo.gl/HoCxk

I have a problem with this function:

```
    $('.message').click(function(){
    alert("it works");
    var clicked_msg=$(this);
    $('#current_message').html(clicked_msg.attr("id"));
});
```

If instead of the above I add an onclick="msgClicked()", and then do something like this:

```
function msgClicked(){
var x=document.getElementById("current_message");alert("it works");x.innerHTML("test");}
```

The jQuery library is obviously imported as literally everything else is done using the jQuery framework and all the other functions implemented on the messaging system are jQuery. Everything works perfect there but for some reason I can't figure out what is wrong with this one.

If any of you are willing to help out and you need to see what is actually going on, please let me know and I will create an account for you on my website. Removing all the protection from the content would take a looong long time.

Comment: Could you post your html as well?

Comment: Post a representative sample ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) on a site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), that lets us see what you're doing and what you're working with. Post the smallest sample that reproduces the problem. Replace anything sensitive with '[Lorem Ipsum](http://lipsum.com/)' text. Many of us will happily review your code if it's easy to get to, but asking us to register our interest and then wait while you create an account for us and then log in to your site first..? That's a little too close to work for me (if not others).

Comment: David if I may I will provide you with a temporary account. It will literally take 10 seconds to see what the problem is.

Comment: Are you generating the clickable items programatically?  If so, you need to use .live or .on depending on your flavor of jQuery.

Comment: check if there is jQuery conflict . use jQuery instead just to test

Comment: So this code is working for me, do you have JQuery referenced in your page?

Comment: thank you Brian Hoover. Excellent suggestion. My sanity is no longer in great danger. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you?

Usually these little annoyances are caused because:

- You made a typo (such as .message being incorrectly spelled in either JS or the HTML)
- You are trying to assign this function to an element which has not been yet created

Just to be sure, try this:

```
alert($('.message').length)
$('.message').click(function(){
    alert("it works");
    var clicked_msg=$(this);
    $('#current_message').html(clicked_msg.attr("id"));
});
```

If it outputs 0, it's because one of the two problems above might be happening, and then, try this:

```
$(function(){
    alert('The page loaded!');
    alert('.message elements in page: ' + $('.message').length);
    $('.message').click(function(){
        alert("it works");
        var clicked_msg=$(this);
        $('#current_message').html(clicked_msg.attr("id"));
    });
});
```

If you don't get any alert messages, there's something wrong with your jQuery import, and it might be a conflict (such as including jQuery twice!)

If the .message elements in page are more than 0, then it was the second issue (you were trying to assign the .click event to an element which hadn't been yet created)

And if it still says 0 elements, then there are no elements with class "message" created.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Cheers!